# Paramiko: Whats the difference between various timeouts?

Tags: python, paramiko

We have multiple timeouts in the Paramiko library, which seems confusing on which to set when. The doc tried to describe them, but I don't understand their use cases.  Like, when should I use one over the other?

[Connect method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect)

1. **timeout**:  an optional timeout (in seconds) for the TCP connect
2. **banner_timeout**: an optional timeout (in seconds) to wait for the SSH banner to be presented.
3. **auth_timeout**: an optional timeout (in seconds) to wait for an authentication response.

[Exec_command method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command)

1. **timeout**: set command’s channel timeout. See Channel.settimeout

Answer (score 1):

[`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) method:

- `timeout` – TCP connection opening timeout (but maybe also for some other socket operations). But also timeout for SSH negotiation. Default is no timeout.
- `banner_timeout` – After TCP connection is opened, how long to wait for the server to anything (that is SSH banner). Default is 15 seconds.
- `auth_timeout` – How long to wait for an authentication response (that imo self-explanatory). Default is 30 seconds.

[`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) method:

- `timeout` – How long to wait for "exec" channel to open. And subsequently timeout for each output reading. Default is no timeout.